# How can I set up free shipping?

Tags: 7, commerce

I am having trouble setting up free shipping on my Commerce project.  I added the Free Shipping module, but when I go to configure, I don't have any options.

The shipping costs for all of our products are absorbed by the manufacturer (who also drop-ships the product, so we don't care about FedEx, UPS, etc).  Therefore, I want to show a free shipping line item during checkout.

I installed the Shipping module (7.x-2.x-dev), and I don't see options to create Shipping Services or Shipping Methods.

How can I configure our store so all products are free shipping?  I watched a few screencasts, but none of them seemed to apply to what I'm wanting to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [Flat Rate](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_flat_rate) module to do the same. You can set free shipping with help of this module very easily.

Once you enable the module, navigate to `Store->Configuration->Shipping->Shipping Method->Flat Rate`.

You will find Flat Rate under `Shipping Method` tab. Click `Add a flat rate service`.

Add something kind of Free Shipping, give it `Title`, `Display title` & `Base Rate` as 0.

Now visit **Shipping Service** tab. You will find your added flat rate service in there. Click `Configure Component` & put any condition you like e.g. `Data Comparison` to `commerce-order:commerce-order-total:amount` for any amount.

Now When ever your condition matches, this Free shipping service will apply if you have put **Shipping service** in **Shipping pane** under **Store->Configuration>Checkout settings**.